# hyperledger fabric run first-network of fabric-samples error on Mac

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I do all the things just according to the official tutorial: https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.0/getting_started.html

But it still does not work. Errors display as below:
[image]

My environment variables are set like this:
[image]
the red part is go and platform-specific binaries.

btw, I check the first error. It said: "open /opt/gopath/src/xxx...: permission denied". But there‘s no path to there:
[image]

I found this directory is set in first-network/base/docker-compose-base.yaml:
[image]

It makes me very confused. Anyone can help me?

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

I just solve this problem by getting help from another place:)

1. check ownership of files under fabric-samples folder and I found all the files belong to root.
2. then I need to take ownership for my user: sudo chown -R [my user] *

then it works!